# NSFileManager createFileAtPath works in simulator but fails on device

Tags: ios, ipad, nsfilemanager

I am trying to write some image data to disk on iOS, but while it's working perfectly in the Simulator, when I try it on a real iPad it fails (returns 0).

```
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:imageData attributes:nil];
```

The path in question looks something like this: `/Library/Caches/_0_0_0_0_1100_1149.jpg` and I've also tried `/Documents/...`.

Is there any way to actually get an error code or something beyond just success/fail?

Comment: Don't downvote without leaving a constructive comment, please. This isn't YouTube.

Comment: What is `filePath` and how is it obtained?

Comment: It's just constructed. That does appear to be the problem. Apparently the `/Library/Caches/` directory is not actually at `/Library/Caches/`. Misleading documentation.

Comment: You don't have access to `/Library/Caches/` on an iOS device. Unless the file path is in your applications directory then you can't write to it without jailbreaking.

Comment: I'm also frustrated about the reason of downvoting questions without the explanation. +1 for justice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simulator does not simulate the sandboxing of the file system that is enforced on a device. You can write anywhere on the sim, but on a device writing anywhere but one of your designated directories will fail.

I'm guessing that your path is badly formed somehow. Try logging your path and the path you get from NSCachesDirectory (as shown in your second post.) They are almost certainly different.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you have to programmatically obtain the directory. The iOS file system is not sandboxed like I expected.

```
NSString* pathRoot = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES )[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing image data, why not try writing via NSData's [[`writeToFile: options: error:`] method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile%3aoptions%3aerror%3a), the "error" parameter for which can give you some really useful hints as to why your file isn't writing.

Comment: Tried that as well, but same result. I think perhaps the path is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is illogical:

```
if ( !( [ fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:documentDBFolderPath error:&error ]))
```

You are checking if the method exists, not if it succeeded!!

I have some relevant code I've used in my project, I hope it may be help you some way or another:

```
-(void)testMethod {

    NSString *resourceDBFolderPath;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentDBFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"plans.gallery"];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentDBFolderPath];

    if (success){
        NSLog(@"Success!");
        return;
    } 
    else {
        //simplified method with more common and helpful method 
        resourceDBFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plans" ofType:@"gallery"];

        //fixed a deprecated method
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:documentDBFolderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:documentDBFolderPath           
                              error:&error];

        //check if destinationFolder exists
        if ([ fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentDBFolderPath])
        {
            //FIXED, another method that doesn't return a boolean.  check for error instead
            if (error)
            {
                //NSLog first error from copyitemAtPath
                NSLog(@"Could not remove old files. Error:%@", [error localizedDescription]);

                //remove file path and NSLog error if it exists.
                [fileManager removeItemAtPath:documentDBFolderPath error:&error];
                NSLog(@"Could not remove old files. Error:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```